# Soliciting for upvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions

[In the comments to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222357/finding-tension-of-ropes-between-objects-attached-via-pulleys-on-an-inclined-pla) I advised that giving a full answer to a HW&E question is not what we should do.

The question which contains nothing of conceptual value, is clearly a HW question and isn't well formatted, appears eligible for 'close' votes (but I haven't voted to close yet).

After my advice to the member providing the answer the member then asked for upvotes. *Per se* there may be nothing wrong with a bit of self-promotion but is it really acceptable? And what would happen to any upvotes if the question was closed later anyway?

Comment: I think the upvotes are retained even if the question is marked 'closed' or put on 'hold', the upvotes gained from the question is deducted only after the question is removed from the site.

Comment: Since you mentioned it, I closed the question (it was off-topic HW) and deleted the answer.

Comment: I don't understand this kind of question; if there is nothing wrong *per se* (nothing *in and of itself* wrong) with X then what would it not be a contradiction if X were not 'really' (objectively, in fact) acceptable?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: I said it *may* be acceptable but asked if it *really* was. I didn't *say* there was *nothing per se* wrong with it, I *asked* about that. My concern would be clearer if you could still see the comments to the now deleted answer.

Answer (score 3):

> *Per se* there may be nothing wrong with a bit of self-promotion but is it really acceptable?

As a one-time thing, it doesn't matter.

If someone says something like "please upvote this answer" (or worse, "please upvote my answer [link]" posted somewhere else), that is somewhat frowned upon, and if they make a *habit* of it, they can expect to get a stern talking-to from the regulars, if not also the mods. On the other hand, "please upvote this answer if you think it's correct and useful" is just a reminder of what we should be doing anyway, so that's fine. Basically, a lot depends on context.

> And what would happen to any upvotes if the question was closed later anyway?

Nothing happens to votes when a question is closed.

If the question is *deleted*, then under most circumstances the reputation from any votes on that question or its answers will be revoked. The main exception is when a deleted post has been visible for 60 days and had a score of 3 or more at the time of deletion. More [details are on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/56541).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not clear on the difference between closed and deleted. Do closed questions become deleted after a time limit?

Comment: Questions like that would be deleted now or later. So, what's the point of upvoting if we know it's a pure _check-my-work_ or _carry-where-I-m-stuck_ problems? Anyone can ask for anything; we don't need to pay heed to every undue favour.

Comment: @Gert I suggest reading the relevant FAQ questions on Meta SE. In short, closed questions are visible to everybody but cannot be answered. Deleted questions are only visible to 10k+ users and mods, and cannot be answered or commented on. Closed questions eventually get deleted under some circumstances.

Comment: @user36790 why would you want to upvote those questions anyway? ;-)

Comment: @DavidZ: I've seen answers/questions being upvoted *knowing* they would be closed later. Happens frequently.

Comment: @Gert oh, I know it happens, I just don't understand why people do it in most cases.

Comment: @DavidZ: Spite? There are members who don't like the quality control policies of this site, that is obvious. Some will upvote silly questions/answers for that reason alone, I think.

Comment: @Gert ok, sure. I should have said I don't understand any _valid_ reason to do it, in most cases.